# What's the problem I with my installtion of packages in R?

Tags: r

When I install packages in my new computer, I find that there always a wrong message which says:

> Error in install.packages : .Internal(unlink) received 3 arguments,but
>   it can use 4 arguments at most

Anybody knows what's the question about and how can I solve it? May reinstall Rstudio can solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which command did you use for which package? Which OS are you using and is this all of the error message?

Comment: I use 'install packages' under the tools menu and any package I try will cause that problem,and my system is windows 10 home edition and the problem happens on R-4.0.1.  After I install the 3.6.3 R edition, it seems that this problem disappears, quiet strange.

Comment: @RyanSun That's really strange. Maybe for helping you we'll need some additional information. Can you please run `sessionInfo()`, edit your question and insert the output of that command? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry that I have uninstalled R-4.0.1 from my computer and now I use the 3.6.3 edition. And just now I reinstall the 4.0.1 version on my computer and it works well, there seems no problem now. But I find the error message from my history, the message has some chinese characters and I translate it into english, the translation may not be accurate. 
The message is "Error in install.packages :. Internal (unlink) received 3 parameters, but it can only use 4 at most". and sometimes this will accur:"Error in print.default(item$value) : invalid printing width".
Thank you for your kind heart!